# Refreshing the page and check for text every 10 seconds in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I have a jenkins job which runs for 15 to 30 minutes. I want to check the page_source for the text 'success' or 'failure'.
If both are not present, I want to refresh and check again every ten seconds. Please guide me. I am using python-selenium
Here is my script so far.

```
src = driver.page_source
success = re.search(r'Finished: SUCCESS', src)
failure = re.search(r'Finished: FAILURE', src)

if success:
    print ('success')
if failure:
    print ('failure')
else:
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing to call the re.search again. You can wrap your search thing in a function and use recursion.

```
def foo():
    src = driver.page_source
    success = re.search(r'Finished: SUCCESS', src)
    failure = re.search(r'Finished: FAILURE', src)

    if success:
        print ('success')
    if failure:
        print ('failure')
    else:
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(5)
        foo() ## your function gets called again

foo() ## call your function for the first time
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I changed that program a little, just added, elif failure.